# Javascript framework for GUI eye candy

Tags: jquery, django, javascript-framework, scriptaculous, ember.js

Of the major Javascript frameworks (jQuery, MooTools, Dojo, Prototype etc), which would be most suitable for build a graphics-intensive online editor? That is, the application I have in mind would have very little text, but instead feature drag-droppable widgets, realtime animation, and cute effects. Manipulating the DOM is of little interest. Maintaining a relationship between GUI elements and server-side (Django) data is crucial.

I hope I don't fall afoul of SO's anti-shopping laws, but it's difficult to find comparisons for specific purposes.

My under-researched impressions so far:

- jQuery is primarily a DOM-manipulation toolkit, but has some pretty GUI stuff too
- MooTools is a more generic enhancement to JavaScript, but also has the "More" which gives transitations and such, but perhaps not full blown widgets?
- Scriptaculous puts all its eggs in the eye candy basket, but no idea how it stacks up otherwise
- ember.js is said to be a generational improvement in client side GUI frameworks (with UI bindings etc), but is under-documented.

I guess I don't yet know enough about this kind of development to make a sensible decision between them, so all thoughts, comments, pointers etc appreciated.

Comment: Interesting stuff. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: 4 votes to close already. I'll never understand why SO wants to prevent this kind of question.

Comment: @SteveBennett - The reason it doesn't really fit is because everyone's going to have their own opinion on what's "best", or what the right frameworks are. It will simply devolve into a list of peoples' favorite things, which doesn't fit well for a site that demands concrete questions and answers.

Comment: IMHO that's incorrect. There's a big difference between "This is my favourite, so there" and "This is a good fit for those requirements, and here's why".

Answer (score 0):

I second the recommendation for jQuery UI. Nearly unlimited options for themes on available widgets, and performance-wise I've found it to be the most lightweight of the JavaScript libraries for visual effects.

Answer (score 0):

The choice of library is about more than built-in eye-candy. Any library can do anything your mind can dream up; the important part is finding something you feel comfortable using and, for lack of a better word, "clicks" with you. You're going to be spending a lot of time with whatever you choose regardless; you want that time to be enjoyable. Try out all of them and see which you like better.

Comment: Haha, well maybe not *all*, but each has it's own style and is own benefits. Perhaps, try to find a walkthrough or tutorial for a handful, and run through them. The idea is to get a feel of what it's like to work in each one. You should start to feel yourself leaning to one or another, so then, you can investigate those that click with your more deeply. It's a bit of personal thing, really, and the better the fit is for you, the more productive you'll be.